# How can I loop through the JSON response object to remove the property labels?

Tags: javascript, json

```
// GET - Get login settings
router.route('/login/settings').get((req, res) => {
  let settings =[];
  pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
    client.query('SELECT * FROM public.settings', (err, result) => {
      settings = result.rows;
      res.json({
          settings,
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I have this code in my API routing that returns the following JSON object:

```
{
  "settings": [
    {
      "key": "TwoFactorAuth",
      "value": "false"
    },
    {
      "key": "sessionTimeout",
      "value": "200"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I write a loop in the routing code to change the JSON response object to look like this:

```
{
  "settings": [
    {
      "TwoFactorAuth": "false"
    },
    {
      "sessionTimeout": "200"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please try something, and ask about any difficulties you find doing it. Remember to post a [mcve] too.

Answer (score 1):

Change the shape of the result.rows objects by mapping over the array.

Change line 6 from:

```
settings = result.rows;
```

To:

```
settings = result.rows.map(setting => ({[setting.key]:setting.value}))
```

Should do it

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the `settings` array and create a new object with one property. The name of the property comes from the `key` element of the original element, and the value of the property comes from the `value` element. Then replace the array element with this.

```
var settings = response.settings;
for (var i = 0; i < settings.length; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[settings[i].key] = settings[i].value;
    settings[i] = obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding variable as key to some object you can use [key] notation.
try this for setting object to update :

```
settings  = settings.map((data) => {
    var object = {};
    object[data.key] = data.value;
    return object;
});
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this working snippet :**

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "settings": [
    {
      "key": "TwoFactorAuth",
      "value": "false"
    },
    {
      "key": "sessionTimeout",
      "value": "200"
    }
  ]
};

var res = jsonObj.settings.map(function(item) {
  var x={};
  x[item.key] = item.value;
  return x;
});

console.log(res);
```